# Bootstrap with customized font size and input-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a customized bootstrap with font-size of 13px and line-height 1.538461538 (20/13) as you could see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=e3983f05f0f6e6781b3a9ce73dea2df5).

However when I'm using input-group with input-group-btn the elements are not align as you can seek [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SbkjcRBoIAtuGVYwK6zu?p=preview).

How I should config the bootstrap to work with a 13px font-size and keep the align of components? The basic code of the component with input-group is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
      <label>Foo</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Go!</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "height:100%" for this css section

```
.input-group .form-control:first-child, .input-group-addon:first-child, .input-group-btn:first-child>.btn, .input-group-btn:first-child>.btn-group>.btn, .input-group-btn:first-child>.dropdown-toggle, .input-group-btn:last-child>.btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle), .input-group-btn:last-child>.btn-group:not(:last-child)>.btn
```

The wrapper class "input-group" have the height 34 pixels. So all your input need to have that size to perfect align.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to adjust the factor of the line height by a value bigger than the target size (20px) when multiplied by font size (13px). In my case, 1.538461538 should be 1.538461539.